# How to queue email in a job with attachment laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, laravel-queue

I have created a queue job to send an email to my batch of users it works fine when I send an email with an attachment. But when I add the file to queue I get an error that says unable to serialize content.

[image: Here is the error message when I run my code]
and here is my code

```
$emailJob = (new SendNewsletter($id, $request->flag, $attachments))->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(3));
        dispatch($emailJob);
```

Comment: you should be saving that uploaded file somewhere (as it will be gone after the request otherwise) then pass that filepath to your job

Comment: Thank you @logbox, but the problem is after saving my file I want an array of my file with all file contents so that I can manipulate the file to send to the other API, because an email is sent by another API so the endpoint expects to receive file in a certain format (containing type, size,mime-type, etc)

Comment: once you save the file, you can read it and do what ever you want to with it

Comment: And how should I know that the emails have all sent so that I can delete file to minimize a batch of unnecessary files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not include your file in the job directly. Rather do something like this:

1. Store the file on disk
2. Create a job using the file path of the file on disk
3. When processing the job:

   1. Retrieve the file from disk
   2. Send your newsletter
   3. Delete the file from disk

Comment: Thank you so much, I followed procedures and my attachments are sent